# What is a closed chain (or circuit) that is used in solving a transportation problem (a special type of linear programming problem)?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

What is a closed chain (or circuit) that is used in solving a transportation problem (a special type of linear programming problem)?
I'm having some problems with it. Please clarify it. I have [posted this](http://mathhelpboards.com/advanced-applied-mathematics-16/meaning-closed-chain-12676.html#post60561) on Math Help Boards as well.